# How to format timestamp unix into date in amcharts4

Tags: javascript, html, css, amcharts, amcharts4

I'm looking to format `1555596901` into a readable date like 2019/04/19 11h52.
Here is the code :

```js
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

function createChart(htmlElement){
  var chart = am4core.create(htmlElement, am4charts.XYChart);
  chart.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";

  chart.data = [
    {
      category: "1555596901",
      value1: 1,
      value2: 5,
      value3: 3,
      value4: 3
    },
    {
      category: "1555611301",
      value1: 10,
      value2: 8,
      value3: 6,
      value4: 4
    }
  ];

  chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();

  chart.colors.step = 2;

  var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
  categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "category";
  categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
  categoryAxis.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";

  var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());  
  valueAxis.min = 0;
  valueAxis.renderer.minWidth = 35;

  var series1 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
  series1.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(80);
  series1.columns.template.tooltipText = "{name}: {valueY.value}";
  series1.name = "Series 1";
  series1.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
  series1.dataFields.valueY = "value1";
  series1.stacked = true;
  series1.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";

  var series2 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
  series2.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(80);
  series2.columns.template.tooltipText = "{name}: {valueY.value}";
  series2.name = "Series 2";
  series2.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
  series2.dataFields.valueY = "value2";
  series2.stacked = true;
  series2.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";

  var series3 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
  series3.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(80);
  series3.columns.template.tooltipText = "{name}: {valueY.value}";
  series3.name = "Series 3";
  series3.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
  series3.dataFields.valueY = "value3";
  series3.stacked = true;
  series3.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";

  var series4 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
  series4.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(80);
  series4.columns.template.tooltipText = "{name}: {valueY.value}";
  series4.name = "Series 4";
  series4.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
  series4.dataFields.valueY = "value4";
  series4.stacked = true;
  series4.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";
  
  return chart;
}

let chart1 = createChart("chartdiv");
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

As you can see it doesn't format the timestamp. I saw in the doc I need to use `chart.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";` for formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format the unix timestamp to JavaScript Date object by doing this.

```
const date1 = new Date(1555596901 * 1000);
console.log(date1);
```

Then, you can format it to dd/mm/yyyy by doing this;

```js
    
const formatDate = inputDate => {
    const date1 = new Date(inputDate * 1000);

    let day = date1.getDate();
    let month = date1.getMonth() + 1;
    const year = date1.getFullYear();
    if (day < 10) {
      day = '0' + dd;
    } 
    if (month < 10) {
      month = '0' + month;
    } 
    const formattedDate = `${day}/${month}/${year}`
    return formattedDate;
}

//formatDate(1555596901);
console.log(formatDate(1555596901));
```

And now, on your original code, you simply need to add the `formatDate` function stated above, and then map it over your chart.data as shown below.

```
chart.data = [
    {
      category: "1555596901",
      value1: 1,
      value2: 5,
      value3: 3,
      value4: 3
    },
    {
      category: "1555611301",
      value1: 10,
      value2: 8,
      value3: 6,
      value4: 4
    }
  ];

const formatDate = inputDate => {
    const date1 = new Date(inputDate * 1000);

    let day = date1.getDate();
    let month = date1.getMonth() + 1;
    const year = date1.getFullYear();
    if (day < 10) {
      day = '0' + dd;
    } 
    if (month < 10) {
      month = '0' + month;
    } 
    const formattedDate = `${day}/${month}/${year}`
    return formattedDate;
}

chart.data = chart.data.map(element => {
  element.category = formatDate(element.category)
  return element;
});

console.log(chart.data)
```

Comment: How do I apply it for amcharts4 ?

Comment: @executable Sorry I forgot to include that part in my post. I will update my answer. Basically, I am mapping that function to the dates.

Comment: Thank you, i'll wait for the full snippet. I'm new to amchart4

Comment: @executable alright, I have updated it. This is how you can use that function on your code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. A little question, how can I map for an external ressource `chart.datasource.url` ?

Comment: Hmm, I don't really understand your question. Do you mean, you want to include `url` onto each object within `chart.data`..? Or is it something else

Comment: I'm getting data from an external ressource like `chart.dataSource.url = "data.php"`

Comment: Does the changing of date format from timestamp to string affects the chart data also? If so this will affects the performance of chart when the data is more because performance affects when the date is in string format.